# kube-cluster running, but no DNS

Tags: kube-dns

excuse the extreme newbiness... I have done docker and kube courses on linux academy.  I have a kube cluster master and 3 minions running on centos7  from repo =http://cbs.centos.org/repos/virt7-docker-common-release/x86_64/os/  kube version 1.5.2 working but as I went to set up an example guest book application, I found I have no DNS.  Have found documents about  how to test DNS works, but can't seem to find how to fix it if it isn't there..

Answer (score 0):

DNS is an essential addon and is usually applied by kubeadm on it's own towards the end of a `kudeadm init` workflow but probably in the older version of this isn't the case. you can manually apply dns by this command `kubeadm alpha phase addon kube-dns [Options]` [ref](https://www.mankier.com/1/kubeadm-alpha-phase-addon-kube-dns)

In case kubeadm that doesn't work then you can use this yaml and modify accordingly https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/deployments/kube-dns.yaml